# filters in depth-wise vs regular convolutional neural networks

Tags: machine-learning, conv-neural-network, convolution

I am a little confused in the differences in filters/kernels when it comes to depthwise vs convolutional neural networks. For example, lets say for each case, the input image is 8x8x3. In depthwise there would be 3 filters (say 3x3x1) and in reg conv2d there would be 1 filter (3x3x3). Is this correct?

In depthwise, each of the 3 filters are different. In reg conv2d, is each filter 'channel' (is that the right term?) different? Or are they all same?

If they are different, how do these 2 operations differ? I know in dw, you can include a channel multiplier (so that the output depth would always be a multiple of its input depth). In reg conv2d, you could have multiple 3x3x3 filters, increasing the output depth as well.

So basically I am a little confused what the differences are.

Answer (score 0):

The differences are in the number of parameters (and therefore multiplication operations and therefore speed) for achieving the same output size, thanks to the separability concept. If you are a veteran of image convolutions, you probably know that some 3x3 filters can be separated into two 1x3 filters (the sobel filter being the most famous example). Thus the same calculation can be done with only 6 parameters instead of 9. Depthwise is applying that concept to separate the spatial part of a convolution from the channel part - do a spatial convolution on one channel at a time, then add a standard 1x1 convolution layer to alter the number of channels. This uses far fewer parameters and therefore far fewer multiplications.

Your specific example is actually incorrect (or at least misleading) because the 3 depthwise filters give an output of 8x8x3 while the single conv filter gives an output of 8x8x1. But even so, as you have rightly hinted at, one can indeed create a single standard convolution layer that gets the same answer - the point is just that the latter has more parameters and is therefore slower. In your example to get the same output as the depthwise case you would need 3 filters and therefore 3x the number of parameters as the depthwise case, although we are cheating a bit relative to the typical case by not having the extra 1x1 channel-altering layer so let's fix that. In general if you wanted to switch your example to output 8x8xN, the standard method would use Nx3x3x3 parameters while the depthwise method would use 3x3x3 + Nx3x1x1 - so 27N vs (3N + 27).

In theory one might expect the separability restriction to decrease the learning capacity, but I guess in practice this appears to either not be the case or is just extremely minimal and therefore worth the speed tradeoff. Maybe there is a strong tendency for "useful" filters to be separable - again Sobel would serve as a great example - but I don't personally know of any evidence to support that.

This article is a very helpful and much fuller explanation:
https://towardsdatascience.com/a-basic-introduction-to-separable-convolutions-b99ec3102728